# Python pip is not working and giving exception urlopen error [Error 10051]

Tags: python-2.7, pip

I am setting up an environment with Python 2.7 (32 bit) on a Windows XP 32 bit computer.

Python 2.7 installed smoothly (I used the Windows installer). After this I have installed setuptools (also using the Windows installer) and subsequently installed pip (I unpacked the pip tar file into a directory, and ran `python setup.py install`).

I have also installed Apache and mod_wsgi, configured them and wrote a simple page in Python, which is displayed correctly by the web server.

So far so good. Now I want to install `virtualenvwrapper-win` using pip. Since I am behind a proxy, I used `--proxy`. My command line looks like this:

```
pip install --verbose --proxy myproxy --use-mirrors --timeout 240 --download D:\cache virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Here I have the same error message many times:

```
Could not fetch URL http://c.pypi.python.org/simple/virtualenvwrapper-win/: <urlopen error [Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.>
```

and finally:

```
 DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for virtualenvwrapper-win
```

After spending 4 hours trying to solve this I have no clue as to how to continue.

Note that the very same steps with Python 2.7 64 bit gave no problem at all (I got virtualenv running within minutes). The reason why I am using Python 32 bit can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2) in section **Windows Binary Downloads**.

Any hint to what is going wrong with `pip install` would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `-r` option with `https://crate.io`. Crate is a fantastic website which mirrors PyPI as well and is very reliable. It syncs every 2 minutes with PyPI so it should be up-to-date unless you just released a package.

Comment: I am already using the `--use-mirrors` option. I will try using crate.

Comment: I completely missed that somehow. >_< Either way, try using crate or try adding it to your list of mirrors in your .pypirc file. The `c` mirror also may have been taken off-line.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17701243/1378264) is a related answer about using mirrors.