# Python - download packages from own server

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

I wonder how can I force setup.py install command to download packages (via pip) from my server. I can get pip my server address but every dependecies are downloaded from pip server.

Maybe solution is pip.ini/pip.conf?

Tomek

Answer (score 3):

[From the docs](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html), you can use the:

```
--use-mirrors --mirrors <url>
```

flag in `pip` to specify which mirror to use.

From command line, you can also speicify mirrors.  For example:

```
pip install -i http://d.pypi.python.org/simple $PACKAGE
```

Comment: Tahnk You for the answer. Ok, so I should set this flags in pip.conf if I'd like to use setup.py install? 

"use mirrors as fallback if main server is down" but I don't want use main server, only my own server.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following lines to setup.cfg worked for me:

```
[easy_install]
index_url = https://some_server/c_adas_cip_pypi_v/simple
```